# Trying to load in stuff via JSON file, but it won't load the clones separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the `<html>` that I want to clone (and fill in with the JSON file):

```
<div id="events" class="alert alert-info text-black">
  <h4>First tutoring session of the year</h4>
  <div>
    <p id="event_p1"><strong>Date:</strong> September 4, 2013</p>
    <p id="event_p2"><strong>More info:</strong> This coming Tuesday MAO will have its first tutoring session of the year.</p>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Now, this is just the general structure I want to have. Here is the JSON file (just the first 3):

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "titl": "etc",
        "date": "September 4, 2013",
        "stuff": "blah blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "titl": "etc",
        "date": "September 4, 2013",
        "stuff": "blah blah blah blah"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "titl": "etc",
        "date": "September 4, 2013",
        "stuff": "blah blah blah blah"
    }
]
```

And, finally, here's the javascript:

```
    var new_event = function(name, date, text, id){
    var events = $("#events").clone();

    $(events).attr('id',id)
    $(events).find('h4').html(name);
    $(events).find('#event_p1').html(date);
    $(events).find('#event_p2').html(text);

    return events;
  }

  var copy_div = function(){  }

  var loadEvents = function(d){
    $.each(d, function(i){
      var id = "event_" + i;
      var name = "<h4>" +d[i].titl + "</h4>";
      var date = "<p><storng>Date: </strong>" + d[i].date + "</p>";
      var text = "<p><strong>More info: </strong>" + d[i].stuff + "</p>";

      $("#events").append(new_event(name,date,text,id));
    })
  }
    //retrieves the appropriate events JSON file
    $.getJSON('data/events.json', loadEvents);
    copy_div();
```

The goal is to load in the data from the JSON file into the appropriate place of a clone of the html I linked above. For some reason it keeps loading the divs inside of one another, such that it looks like [image: this.]

Notice how they keep getting put inside one another, endlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've solved it. Oops, silly mistake.

If you look above, `$("#events").append(new_event(name,date,text,id));` is loading the events into the element with the `id="events"`, which is the one I cloned originally. To get them to load as separate blocks, the function needs to append them another element with another id. Therefore, I added a `<div>` around the original and had the function spit them out there.

Fun fun.